# Count number of "true" booleans in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an BooleanArray filled with 17 values.
I want to loop through that array and count how many of them are true, or break and set a flag when it reaches a certain amount of true values. So if the array containes 6 booleans that are "true" I want to break the loop and do something.

```
BooleanArray booleanArray = new BooleanArray(17);
booleanArray.add(handler.get(0).getStatus());
booleanArray.add(handler.get(1).getStatus());
booleanArray.add(handler.get(2).getStatus());
booleanArray.add(handler.get(3).getStatus());
booleanArray.add(handler.get(4).getStatus());
//etc...
```

It's how to build this loop I'm not sure on how to.

Comment: Are you sure there is such class BooleanArray  ?

Comment: Can you share the `BooleanArray` class and the `handler` declaration and initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
int trueCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array.get(i) /* or array[i] */) {
        trueCount++;
    }
    if (trueCount >= 6) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the lambdas

```
ArrayList<Boolean> vals = new ArrayList();
   for(boolean val: arr){
       vals.add(val);
   }
   vals.removeIf(el -> el.equals(false));
   return vals.size();
```